# unable delete the tableview rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

If I take the image from gallery that image I stored in array and if I don't want the image need to delete image 
in .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageCustom : UITableViewController
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *arrayRoot;
@end
```

in .m I stored the image in view will appear.

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains 

  (NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *plistPath =

  [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"manuallyData.plist"];

  self.arrayRoot = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

  [self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

then

I am using custom tableview and provide delete option to delete an image but

after deleting the image whenever I moved to next view and come back to that

tableview again appear those deleted images in tableview. I need to delete the

images pemanently? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you implemented the delete functionality on UITableview.

The delete action should remove the row physically from the UITableView, but also remove the entry in the plist, since the DataSource for your table is that plist.  If you do not delete the entry from the plist it will continue to appear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to delete not from gallery, but only from array.

Simply put your CODE in **ViewDidLoad**, instead of **ViewWillAppear**, as **ViewWillAppear** is called whenever your push and pop the view, while **ViewDidLoad** only called once when View is loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need know which array you put the images in.and you need remove the image that you want to delete form the array.and then ,you need reload the tableView.maybe it can be working.